# Jade issue on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am newbie to Nodejs and jade and trying to build simple website to hone my skill. I am using bootstrap and making nav bar, but it keeps showing error message like this ***Unexpected token `tag` expected `text`, `code`, `:`, `newline` or `eos`*** on line 14 a(class="navbar-brand" href="#")home 
My code is

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    title notyet
    link(href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css", rel="stylesheet", integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7", crossorigin="anonymous")
  body(id="page-top" class="index")
    //navigation
    nav(class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top")
      div(class="container")
        //brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display
        div(class="navbar-header page-scroll")
          button(type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1")
          a(class="navbar-brand" href="#")Home
        div(class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1")
          ul(class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right")
            li(class="hidden")
              a(href="#page-top")
            li(class="page-scroll")
              a(href="#")1
            li(class="page-scroll")
              a(href="#")2
```

and my nodejs code is

```
//setting environment
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views','views_files');
app.locals.pretty = true;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//code
app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.render('index')
});

//listen server
app.listen(3000, function(req, res){
  console.log('we are connecting at port 3000');
});
```

Did I miss something?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put a `.` before `Home`, or put it on a new line (and do the same for `1` and `2` for the errors you will get on other lines after that).

Comment: Putting a "." before Home would give the a-tag the class of "Home". I'm assuming he wants the tag to read "Home".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it is saying is that you need to put a space before "Home". Like this:

```
a(class="navbar-brand" href="#") Home
```

Always put a space between you tags and your text. I see you have made the same mistake on a couple of other places.

Comment: thank you! didn't know simple one space can screw up